# Using R to solve a series of simple equations

Tags: r

I'm having trouble understanding the `solve` command in R, even after reading some basic examples and documentation.

Let's say I have the following formula describing the growth rate of an economy:

```
Y = K^α * (AL)^1−α
```

Let's set α = 1/3.  Let's read in a dummy data-frame

```
data <- read.table(text = "
Economy Year y k L
A 1960 100 1 1000
A 2000 1350 27 2000
B 1960 20 2 4000
B 2000 1350 54 8000
", header = TRUE)
```

Now, how would I use the `solve` command (or something more appropriate) to calculate the value of "A" in each of these rows?  Something like this doesn't work obviously:

```
with(data, solve(y, k^(1/3), L^(2/3))
```

Comment: A way to do this consistently, working with a data frame of named columns, is to create a function with your equation rearranged to solve for A and then use either a `for` loop or `sapply `to iterate through rows setting the appropriate column to each variable, calling the function then appending the result to a new column. Using `solve()` in this way might more complicated and not likely much faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the `ompr` Optimization Modelling Package. You need to rearrange the equation to make it work.

```
library(ROI)
library(ROI.plugin.glpk)
library(ompr)
library(ompr.roi)
library(dplyr)

f <- function(y, k, L, alpha){
    MIPModel() %>%
    add_variable(A) %>%
    set_objective(0) %>%
    add_constraint((((y/(k^alpha))^(1/((1-alpha))))/L) == A) %>%
    solve_model(with_ROI(solver = "glpk")) %>% 
    get_solution(A)
}

apply(data[,3:5], 1, function(x) f(y=x['y'],k=x['k'],L=x['L'], alpha=0.3))
#[1] 0.71968567 0.35984284 0.17992142 0.08996071
apply(data[,3:5], 1, function(x) f(y=x['y'],k=x['k'],L=x['L'], alpha=1/3))
#[1] 1.00000000 4.77297077 0.01581139 0.84375000
```

This might be an overkill for this example. But is scalable.

Comment: Hmm.  This looks right, but when I solve by hand I get using `data$A <- with(data, (y / k^(1/3))^(3/2) * (1/L))` I get 1.00000000 4.77297077 0.01581139 0.84375000, which WolframAlpha confirms as correct.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @Parseltongue I used alpha=0.3. Let me check with alpha=1/3

Comment: @Parseltongue The output matches with yours for alpha=1/3.

Comment: Wow... such radically different answers with a little bit of rounding.